# Any simple tool to simulate server load?

Tags: perl, iis, iis-7, automation

I have an IIS server to test for load. But I don't need the tool to give me any performance data. I only want a simple tool/script that would flood my server with requests.

I know about wcat, Jmeter, httperf etc. but those have too many extra features. I don't want all that functionality. Just a simple script would do that would send, say, 100 requests/s. I know this kind of thing is easily done in perl but i don't know perl. Can someone help me out?
Just to flood requests, don't even wait for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ab` [apachebench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) program is well-suited for generating a huge amount of nearly useless requests.

Comment: That is for apache servers only I guess?

Comment: No, the name may be a little misleading, but it'll happily submit HTTP requests to any HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS you should try the [Web Capacity Analysis Tool](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6).

Edit: sorry, didn't notice WCAT in your question. If you just want to hit a server with a lot 
of requests you can use just about any scripting language.

I don't know much Perl either, but [this page nicely explains how to fetch a URL](http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html) - just put that code in a loop and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be free?
You can run up to 50 users with http://loadimpact.com

Comment: 50 users are free, afterwards you have to pay.